# Get Java enum values array in scala

Tags: java, scala, enums

When declaring an enum in Java like this:

```
public enum Weekday {
  MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}
```

you can get a specific value by its assigned integer index like this:

```
Weekday.values()[index]
```

Is there a way to do this in scala accessing an Enum written in Java?

Comment: Weird question ! It's just an array

Comment: Yeah its an array but I found no way of accessing it. Maybe the question is a bit weird though. English is not my native language and I tried to make it understandable in a way I would understand it too :)

Comment: Your english is fine, I just don't understood why you could not just access it as an array like shown in Jean's answer. Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: I did not try Jean's solution and digging through the internet brought no solution so I figured I'd just ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply:

```
Weekday.values()(index)
```

In scala, arrays are accessed via the `apply` function, so also directly via `array(index)`

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was hoping for. Unfortunately I can't accept your answer right now since I have to wait 8 Minutes.